# How do I get the Price an NFT sold (sells) for via the base NFT contract in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, nft, opensea

I'm trying to figure out how to get the highest price and NFT sold (sells) via the base NFT contract in solidity. So, I can possibly map the highestSoldPrice to a TokenId within the collection.

I'm sure there's a clever way to do this.

Thank you and God Bless

EDIT:

Base contracts as in the contract that deploys the NFTs, it would inherit the ERC721 contract.

Comment: By base NFT, do you mean the ERC721 smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have much information about what your talking about, like are you talking about the base ERC721 contract? is it the marketplace contract? is the architecture of the marketplace contract ERC1155? No clue

Since your talking about highest price and NFT Sold , im assuming your talking about the Marketplace contract.

Solutions

- Use a node provider to create a script and aggregate the contracts sold event :>
- Use Covalent API to aggregate the contract event or state variable

If your going with your own script with node provider check out this github for reference :>

- https://github.com/DiverseSolutions/NodeProviderExamples

Comment: Base contracts as in the contract  that deploys the NFTs, it would inherent the ERC721 contract.

I'm sure there's another way to do it other than creating an oracle.

Possibly a fallback function?

Answer (score 0):

```
 uint public highestPrice=0 // initially
 mapping(uint->string) public highestSoldNft
```

When you mint the token, you pass the price as a parameter

```
function mint(string memory tokenUri, uint price) public payable returns(uint){ 
    _safeMint(msg.sender,newTokenId);
    // after minting update the mapping
    if (price > highestPrice){
        delete highestSoldNft[highestPrice]
        setHighestPrice(price)
        setHighestSoldNft(tokenUri,price)
    }}

    function setHighestPrice(uint price) public private {
        highestPrice=price
    }
    
    function setHghestSoldNft(string memory tokenUri,uint price) public private{
        highestSoldNft[price]=tokenUri
    }
```